# Mysqli Prepared statement Update Where IN with multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to update my sql database with the folowing query. What I need is to have the data updated if the id is IN the colomn id. Apart from that I need some other variables to be update for all of these ids. I can do this hardcoded, but how to I add those vairables to this query?

To be exact. In this example I need `$NameResult` and `$NotesResult` update for the rows where the colomn 'id' matches the result from `$_POST["UpdatedID"]`

I cant find a explanation anywhere on how to do this, anyone that can help me with this?

Thise code gives me a error.

```
syntax error, unexpected '$types29' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')' 

$NameResult = "NameTest";
$NotesResult = "NotesTest";
$in8  = str_repeat('?,', count($_POST["UpdatedID"]) - 1) . '?';
$types29 = str_repeat('i', count($_POST["UpdatedID"])); 
$sql8 = "UPDATE account SET name = ?, notes = ? WHERE id IN (0,$in8)";
$stmt8 = $mysqli->prepare($sql8);
$stmt8->bind_param('s,s'$types29,$RankerResult,$NotesResult,...$_POST["UpdatedID"]);
$stmt8->execute();
$stmt8->close();
```

Comment: Anyone that can help??

Comment: What error do you get - it helps understand what is happening.

Comment: Error is in the question. Problem is, how do I add the other variables in the sql query besides id.

Comment: Do you mean as you are missing a comma in `'s,s'$types29`?

Comment: I dont know. Is that realy all there is to it..

Comment: Well. Tried it like this and no succes.  Getting error no data suplied for parameters. 

$stmt8->bind_param('s,s',$types29,$RankerResult,$NotesResult,...$_POST["UpdatedID"]);

Comment: Try with: `$stmt8->bind_param('ss' . $types29, $RankerResult, $NotesResult, ... $_POST["UpdatedID"]);` ... I assuming here that the `...` portion will be other parameters? The deal is to concatenate the bind types for the 1st parameter.